# React: Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a full-stack application in React, but once I compile my application and try to refresh the React browser page, it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

React tells me to check my render function for my GameComponent.jsx.

Here is the GameComponent.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthenticatedRoute from './AuthenticatedRoute.jsx';

import LoginComponent from './LoginComponent.jsx';
import LogoutComponent from './LogoutComponent.jsx';
import WelcomeComponent from './WelcomeComponent.jsx';
import HeaderComponent from './HeaderComponent.jsx';
import FooterComponent from './FooterComponent.jsx';
import ErrorComponent from './ErrorComponent.jsx';

class GameComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
        <div className = "GameComponent">
                <Router>
                    <>
                    <HeaderComponent/>
                    <Switch>
                    <Route path = "/" exact component ={LoginComponent}/>
                    <Route path = "/login" component ={LoginComponent}/>
                    <AuthenticatedRoute path = "/welcome/:name" component ={WelcomeComponent}/>
                    <AuthenticatedRoute path = "/logout" component ={LogoutComponent}/>
                    <Route component = {ErrorComponent}/>
                    </Switch>
                    <FooterComponent/>

                    </>
                </Router>
                
            </div>)
        
    }
}
export default GameComponent;
```

Here is my App.js:

```
import GameComponent from './components/GameComponent';
import './bootstrap.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GameComponent/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am sorry in advance for the messy code/bad principles, I just started learning. If anyone has any ideas, please share!

Comment: Isn't `./WelcomeComponent.jsx` should be `./WelcomeComponent.js`.

Comment: Can you check whether all your imports are default exports or named exports ?

Comment: i dont see anything goes wrong in ```GameComponent``` please check ```children``` component of ```GameComponent``` maybe the problem from the child.